# Finding a common number from the list and placing it in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I have two lists that are formed through a function called **factors** which returns the prime factors of a number. In my task I have to return the common numbers in both the lists to a new list.

```
def factors(n):
    i = 2
    prime_factors = []
    while i*i <= n:
        if n%i == 0:
            prime_factors=prime_factors + [i]
            n //= i
        else:
            i += 1
    if n>1:
        prime_factors=prime_factors + [n]
    return prime_factors


>>>factors(4)
>>>[2,2]
>>>factors(14)
>>>[2,7]
```

I have to find the common number and return it in a new list. I tried my code below and it gave me result list as [2,2], whereas it should only be [2]

```
lst=[]
for element in factors(4):
            if element in factors(14):
                lst=lst+[element]
```

This code gives me the result as [2,2]. Kindly guide me as to how I can get only [2]. Also I am **NOT** allowed to use methods like set, intersection, or zip or stuff from math library. another example:

```
lst1=[2,2,3,3,4,5,6]
lst2=[2,2,3,4,4,7,8]

common_lst=[2,2,3,4]
```

Comment: use **set** and convert it to list at end if needed. instead of `lst=[]` use `lst=set()` and `lst.add(element)`

Comment: perhaps `if element in factors(14) and element not in lst:`?

Comment: I can't use set() if there is any other method kindly tell

Comment: Are you gonna keep vandalizing your question and invalidating answers?

Comment: How would 4, 6 and 8 get into the lists? They're no primes.

Comment: @Manuel that was just an example as to how the common list might look like

Answer (score 0):

(Note: this was for an earlier version of the question, before they vandalized the question to say the math "library" isn't allowed and that they want to keep common duplicates. Oh well, `gcd` is a short one-liner we could write ourselves instead.)

```
>>> from math import gcd
>>> factors(gcd(4, 14))
[2]
```

or

```
>>> [*{*factors(4)} & {*factors(14)}]
[2]
```

(They're not quite equivalent, they solve two different interpretations of the ambiguous question. I actually suspect the first one is the desired one, as otherwise the OP might not have made the `factors` function produce duplicate factors in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` method from the `collections` library would come in handy here. `Counter` takes in a list and returns a dictionary of the number of 'counts' of each value in that list.

```python
from collections import Counter

f4 = factors(4)
f14 = factors(14)

c4 = Counter(f4)
c14 = Counter(f14)

inter = c4 & c14

lst = list(inter.elements())
```

`inter` represents the intersection between the two dictionaries. `list(inter.elements())` simply retrieves the elements of the dictionary as a combination of the key and value and converts the result to a list.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand the question correctly, the only way to solve it is to delete the common numbers as they are found. (To do this i have iterated through the lists backwords to prevent Index errors)

```
lst = []
fctrs_1 = factors(4)
fctrs_2 = factors(14)
for a in range(len(fctrs_1)-1, -1, -1):
    for b in range(len(fctrs_2)-1, -1, -1):
        if fctrs_1[a] == fctrs_2[b]:
            lst.append(fctrs_1[a])
            del fctrs_1[a]
            del fctrs_2[b]
            break # Break to prevent errors 
print(lst)# Output: [2]
```